# Redirect if failure in django views

Tags: python, django

I have this function. I want to execute the following two lines:

```
list = utils.get_connection().get_list_by_id(MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID)
list.subscribe(email_address, {'EMAIL': email_address, 'FNAME': fname, 'LNAME': lname})
```

And if they fail, I want to redirect them to `'/mailing_list_failure'`

Here is the full function:

```
def add_email_to_mailing_list(request):
    if request.POST['email'] and len(request.POST['email']) > 4:
        email_address = request.POST['email']
        fname = request.POST['fname']
        lname = request.POST['lname']
        #If two next lines are failure return to '/mailing_list_failure/'
        list = utils.get_connection().get_list_by_id(MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID)
        list.subscribe(email_address, {'EMAIL': email_address, 'FNAME': fname, 'LNAME': lname})

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/mailing_list_success/')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/mailing_list_failure/')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a `try` / `except` block. I am not a python expert, so let me know if this can be improved, and I'll update it.

```
def add_email_to_mailing_list(request):
    if request.POST['email'] and len(request.POST['email']) > 4:
        email_address = request.POST['email']
        fname = request.POST['fname']
        lname = request.POST['lname']
        #If two next lines are failure return to '/mailing_list_failure/'
        try:
            list = utils.get_connection().get_list_by_id(MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID)
            list.subscribe(email_address, {'EMAIL': email_address, 'FNAME': fname, 'LNAME': lname})
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/mailing_list_success/')
        except:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/mailing_list_failure/')
```

Check out this link:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html